# GEB - How to get value from readonly input

Tags: jquery, groovy, spock, geb

I'm trying to get value from read only input which looks exactly as below:

```
<input id="EmailGeneratorText" class="input-email-input" readonly="" placeholder="Generated email"/>
```

I tried to do it as below:

```
def a = js.exec 'jQuery("input#EmailGeneratorText").val()'
```

but unfortunately it doesn't help

```
System.out.println("value:" + a) // => value:null**
```

I also tried .text() and .value(), but no results.
Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
element.@value
```

Assuming it has a value... In your example html, it doesn't have one

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work.
This is the problem, in html value attribute is not exposed and the input looks exactly as in example, but input on UI is populated with a string, in my case with generated email.
I've tried to check in browser console and I noticed $('#EmailGeneratorText').value()  and $('#EmailGeneratorText').text() don't return value from input, only $('#EmailGeneratorText').val() it do. But how to make geb to execute jquery in this case?

Comment: And you've tried `def a = js.exec('return $("#EmailGeneratorText").val();')` yeah?

Comment: with the `return`? (you don't have `return` in your question)

Comment: Are you sure the input _has_ a value at the time you are getting it?  If it's set asynchronously by the UI, you might just be getting it too soon?  Try wrapping your check in `waitFor { ... }`?

Comment: It doesn't help. This was my first thought and here is how my method looks:
    def generateEmail(){

        asmEmailGeneratorButton.click()
        waitFor {asmEmailGeneratorText}
        def a = js.exec('return $("input#asmEmailGeneratorText").val();')}

Comment: I meant: `asmEmailGeneratorButton.click(); waitFor {  js.exec('return $("input#asmEmailGeneratorText").val();') == 'expected@email.com' }`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 println   $("input",id:"EmailGeneratorText",class:"input-email-input").value()
```

It will definitely work